# How can I programatically get HBA information (or PowerPath details) from a server?

Tags: networking, storage

I'd like to monitor details of my HBA's and not sure how to extract info from my PowerPath console or anything from my QLogic HBA's.

Any detail or information would be great.  From what I can tell, Microsoft uses something called HBAAPI when installing the Exchange Best Practice tools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what information you are looking to capture, you may be able to use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx) to programmatically get this data. Microsoft provides a set of host bus adapter [WMI classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557239%28VS.85%29.aspx). In order to use them you will need to ensure that the following components are installed:

- Hbaapi.dll - Should be in %systemroot%\system32\
- Hbaapi.mof - Should be in %systemroot%\system32\wbem.
- Drivers along with an adapter that is supported

For more information see the [Discovering Fibre Channel Topology through WBEM](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/storage/FCTopology.mspx) article from Microsoft.

Additionally, QLogic may already provide it's own WMI classes or HBA API. This may be another option for you to explore.